# AutoLayout for Container View inside parent View not aligned to layout guides

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, autolayout

I'm really not sure how to put this question into words, so I'll present some incredibly partial screenshots of how the view in question looks. I'd provide more information, but I'm not sure if that'd be in breach of contract. Sorry!

[image]

I have this setup for a Container View (itself inside a navigation controller and THAT inside a tab view) with two views, a Map View and a Table View. The Table View seems to be shunted to the left.

[image]

The strangest thing is that if I tilt the phone to landscape and back to portrait, I get the behaviour I desire.

[image]

Why is this not working on initial view? No code is set up to handle orientation changes anywhere in the app. If I'm missing some vital information that would explain this behaviour, let me know and I'll edit it into my question ASAP, I am completely baffled and not even sure where to begin.

EDIT: I've been searching for similar problems, and found several answers that no longer seem to apply, as they refer to older versions of Xcode and iOS, and concepts like pinning that I haven't come across with storyboarding before.

EDIT 2: AutoLayout constraints: the Map View has Align Center X to Superview, Leading Space to Superview equal to -20, Bottom Space to Container View equal to 0, Top Space to Top Layout Guide equal to 0, and Equal Height to Container View.

The Container View has Align Center X to Superview, Leading Space to Superview equal to -20 Bottom Space to Bottom Layout Guide equal to 0, Top Space to Map View, and Equal Height to Map View.

The view contained within Container View has no direct constraints relating to the parent view, and I'm not entirely sure how that would work in the Storyboard editor.

EDIT 3: I threw together a stripped down demo project showing this problem.

Instructions to recreate the problem:

- Select Item in the tab bar
- Select an option in the next table view
- You should see that the items in the table view in the next view aren't displaying properly.
- Tilting the phone landscape and then back to portrait fixes the problem.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1y48pggs04cz19/ContainerTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: Do you set your constraints in interface builder and what are they?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is interface builder, I'm working with a .storyboard file and I'm not sure if I'm using .xib files, or if they're just being generated somewhere I'm unaware of. EDIT: Just found out enter saves comments! Good to know. Either way, I'll add my constraints to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me ,

**From your Edit 2 :-**

**Leading Space to Superview equal to -20** i think here is the **mistake** .

(**Leading Space**) it should be **+20** in place of **-20**. Try to change it and then check.

You can check Example of Leading space with +20 and -20 in below example.

**Example :-**

[image]

---

Edit 1 :-

[Link for demo with correction](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=43567427922919476818)

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. You don't seem to have the same layout guides as I do, and if I set Leading Space to 20 I get white margins around the container. Plus, when I tilt the phone to landscape and back to portrait they double in size. Also, if you don't mind me asking, what did you use to capture the footage for that gif?

Comment: use https://gyazo.com/ to upload gif image . and now if you give me demo then i can able to help you.

Comment: Okay, I threw together an example project that demonstrates the problems I'm having. Select Item in the tab bar, and then select any of the options in the table view, and you'll see that the items in the table view in the next view aren't displaying properly. You should also notice that tilting the phone landscape and then back to portrait magically fixes the problem. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1y48pggs04cz19/ContainerTest.zip?dl=0

Comment: as i said you gave wrong constrain to tableview. its +20 not -20. check added demo in answer.

Comment: I can see how that fixed it, but I can't find where the constraint is. It looks like you've assigned the constraint to the leading edge instead of the leading margin, though, which fixed the problem. Thanks!